# Android: using if statement to choose table for data insert

Tags: android, sql

I have several database tables in one database.  The user inputs data to be inserted into the database, and one of the spinner values is to designate which table the data should go in.

The insert works fine for one table.  However, as soon as I put an if statement in to have the data put in the correct table, nothing gets inserted anywhere.  The error I get in logcat is "no such table: DATABASE_TABLE", which doesn't make sense to me because without the if statement in there it has no problems inserting.

Here is my code:

**Updated to include full code

```
int id = 0;

//setting up columns
public static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_EXERCISE = "abs";
public static final String KEY_REPS = "reps";
public static final String KEY_TIMETYPE = "timetype";


//setting up the database
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "ExerciseDB";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "ExerciseTable";
private static final String DATABASE_BICEPSTABLE = "BicepsTable";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

//setting up tables
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE_ABS = "CREATE TABLE " + 
DATABASE_TABLE + " (" + 
KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
KEY_REPS + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
KEY_TIMETYPE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
KEY_EXERCISE + " TEXT NOT NULL);";

private static final String DATABASE_TABLE_BICEPS = "CREATE TABLE " + 
DATABASE_BICEPSTABLE + " (" + 
KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
KEY_REPS + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
KEY_TIMETYPE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
KEY_EXERCISE + " TEXT NOT NULL);";

private static String CHOSEN_TABLE = "";


private DbHelper ourHelper;
private static Context ourContext;
private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;


public static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{



    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }



    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // Only uses this method when the database is first created.
        //Sets up the database - telling it the table name and all
        //the column names.
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_TABLE_ABS);

        //syntax used to insert rows into a database on creation
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + DATABASE_TABLE + "(" + KEY_EXERCISE +", " + KEY_REPS +", " + KEY_TIMETYPE + ") VALUES ('Reverse Crunches', '25', 'Reps' );" );



        //setting up Biceps Table
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_TABLE_BICEPS);

        //syntax used to insert rows into a database on creation
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + DATABASE_BICEPSTABLE + "(" + KEY_EXERCISE +", " + KEY_REPS +", " + KEY_TIMETYPE + ") VALUES ('Hammer Curls', '15', 'Reps' );" );



    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // called when database has already been created.
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_BICEPSTABLE);
        onCreate(db);           
    }       
}

public ExerciseDatabase(Context c){
    ourContext = c;
}

//to open the database
public ExerciseDatabase open()throws SQLException{
    ourHelper = new DbHelper(ourContext);
    ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

//to close the database
public void close(){
    ourHelper.close();
}






//to retrieve all the data from the database
public String getData() {
    String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_REPS, KEY_EXERCISE, KEY_TIMETYPE};
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    String result = "";

    int iReps = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_REPS);
    int iExercise = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_EXERCISE);
    int iTimeType = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_TIMETYPE);

    for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
        result = result + c.getString(iExercise) + " " 
        + c.getString(iReps) + " "
        + c.getString(iTimeType) + "\n";
    }

    return result;
}

public String getBicepsData() {
    String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_REPS, KEY_EXERCISE, KEY_TIMETYPE};
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_BICEPSTABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    String result = "";

    int iReps = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_REPS);
    int iExercise = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_EXERCISE);
    int iTimeType = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_TIMETYPE);

    for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
        result = result + c.getString(iExercise) + " " 
        + c.getString(iReps) + " "
        + c.getString(iTimeType) + "\n";
    }

    return result;
}


//to count the number of entries in the database    
public int EntryCount(){

    return (int) DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(ourDatabase,DATABASE_TABLE);

    }

//adds an entry to the database that the user inputs into the text fields   
public long addExercise(String exerciseadd, String repTimeAdd, String timetype, String exercisetype) {

    if (exercisetype == "abs"){
        CHOSEN_TABLE = "DATABASE_TABLE";
    }else if (exercisetype == "biceps"){
        CHOSEN_TABLE = "DATABASE_BICEPSTABLE";
    }

    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(KEY_EXERCISE, exerciseadd);
        cv.put(KEY_REPS, repTimeAdd);   
        cv.put(KEY_TIMETYPE, timetype);
        return ourDatabase.insert(CHOSEN_TABLE, null, cv);


}




//gets an entry from the Reps column by chosen row number (randomly generated in main activity) 
public String getReps(int chosenRow) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (chosenRow == 0){
        ++chosenRow;
    }

    String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_REPS, KEY_EXERCISE, KEY_TIMETYPE};
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, KEY_ID + "=" + chosenRow, null, null, null, null);
    if(c != null){
        c.moveToFirst();
        String exercise = c.getString(0);
        return exercise;
    }
    return null;
}



//gets an entry from the Abs column by chosen row number (randomly generated in main activity) 
public String getExercise(int chosenRow) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (chosenRow == 0){
        ++chosenRow;
    }

    String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_REPS, KEY_EXERCISE, KEY_TIMETYPE};
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, KEY_ID + "=" + chosenRow, null, null, null, null);
    if(c != null){
        c.moveToFirst();
        String reps = c.getString(1);
        return reps;
    }
    return null;
}

//gets an entry from the timetype column by chosen row number (randomly generated in main activity) 
public String getTimeType(int chosenRow) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (chosenRow == 0){
        ++chosenRow;
    }

    String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_REPS, KEY_EXERCISE, KEY_TIMETYPE};
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, KEY_ID + "=" + chosenRow, null, null, null, null);
    if(c != null){
        c.moveToFirst();
        String reps = c.getString(2);
        return reps;
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

Comment: so `DATABASE_TABLE` is invalid name table. add here full code.

Comment: The table can not be considered a variable in SQL -- you need to use dynamic SQL for that, where you construct the SQL as a string before executing the statement.

Comment: @hawaii.five-0 - updated to include full code

Comment: Is `DATABASE_TABLE` the actual name of the table or is it a `String` variable? If it's the latter you shoud use `CHOSEN_TABLE = DATABASE_TABLE;` (without the quotes.

Comment: @OMG Ponies - can you give me an example of that?  I'm not sure what you mean.  Also you guys should post in the answer section, so I can give someone credit for the working solution.

Comment: @MisterSquonk - DATABASE_TABLE is the actual name of the table.  The variable is CHOSEN_TABLE.  I tried taking the quotes away anyway and it gave me this error:    06-03 19:22:18.248: E/Database(9189): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "(": syntax error: , while compiling: INSERT INTO (reps, abs, timetype) VALUES(?, ?, ?);

Comment: @SillyFidget : No...`ExerciseTable` is the name of the table. ;)

Comment: @MisterSquonk - ohhhh you're right :) well like i said above, I tried removing the quotes and I got that error.  Any suggestions?

Comment: If I initialize like this:  private static String CHOSEN_TABLE = DATABASE_TABLE;  ...  I do not get an error, but it will only insert into DATABASE_TABLE, even if I choose the other one.  It seems the variable does not change.  Is my conditional syntax wrong?

Comment: @MisterSquonk:  oh. my. goodness.  thank you.  lol it worked!  I've been trying to figure this out for hours.  Please post that below so i can give you credit.

Comment: @SillyFidget : See my edited question about comparing strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `DATABASE_TABLE` is a String variable, you should use `CHOSEN_TABLE = DATABASE_TABLE;` (without the quotes)....and the same for `CHOSEN_TABLE = DATABASE_BICEPSTABLE;` (no quotes).

Also, you can't use `==` for comparing strings. Use...

```
if (exercisetype.equals("abs")){
    CHOSEN_TABLE = DATABASE_TABLE;
}else if (exercisetype.equals("biceps")){
    CHOSEN_TABLE = DATABASE_BICEPSTABLE;
}
```

Comment: quick question for future reference.  Does this only apply to SQL (not being able to compare strings with ==)?  Or is this true always?

Comment: @SillyFidget : Always true for Java. Using `==` compares references of objects, `String.equals(...)` compares the actual `String` 'values'.